# What kind of cable is this? (standing desk motor to power supply)

Tags: electrical, cables

I need an extender for the cable below. It's directly attached to a motor that powers an electric standing desk. What kind of cable is it?

[image: Cable]

More images of the cable and power supply:

1. Cable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3N09.png
2. Power supply: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r17mW.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LrJw.png
4. Text on cable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj2G2.png

Comment: There's no longer a 1-picture limit for new users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to be certain from the image, but it very much resembles this connector:

[image: molex 39-01-2060 connector]

It's a Molex 39-01-2060 connector and lists on the [Molex web site](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0039012060_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml) as well.

Comment: Yup, it really looks like it's in the Molex Mini-Fit family.   I take it Mini-Fit Jr. Is a smaller version of Mini-Fit?

Answer (score 1):

That is a polarized latching Molex connector used typically for low voltage applications.

Comment: Molex makes an absolutely *insane* number of connectors that fit your description...

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a Molex brand connector..

Comment: Molex makes a *zillion* connectors...